# I cannot get my program to stop repeating my first statement

Tags: python, loops, random

Python just keeps repeating back to me "How many random numbers do you want?" and won't move on to the next input.

I've tried most things I could think of.

```
do_program = True
while(do_program):
while(True):
    try:
        number_of_numbers = float(input("How many random numbers do you want?"))
        if(number_of_numbers < 0):
            print("Negative numbers are not allowed.")
        continue
    except ValueError:
        print("The value you entered is invalid. Please enter numerial values only.")
    else:
        break

while(True):
    try:
        lowest_number = float(input("What is the lowest random number you want?"))
        if(lowest_number < 0):
            print("Negative numbers are not allowed.")
        continue
    except ValueError:
        print("The value you entered is invalid. Please enter numerial values only.")
    else:
        break

while(True):
    try:
        highest_number = float(input("What is the highest random number you want?"))
        if(highest < 0):
            print("Negative numbers are not allowed.")
        continue
    except ValueError:
        print("The value you entered is invalid. Please enter numerial values only.")
    else:
        break
import random
print("The numbers were written to randomnum.txt.")

def main():
    for count in range(number_of_numbers):
        number = random.randint(lowest_number, highest_number)
        print(number)
main()
```

Right now I just want to focus on getting to my second and third input statements.

Answer (score 0):

After successfully reading `number_of_numbers` the code `break`s out of the inner `while(True)` loop and then resumes the outer `while(do_program)` loop. This causes the same code to be executed over and over. Perhaps rework your code to process the input before returning to the main loop?